# COMPILE ERROR: Incompatible value type System.Address for Map<String,String>

Tags: soql

```
List<Account> accVar = [SELECT id,phone,BillingAddress FROM Account];

 Map<String,String> findAccountName = New Map<String,String>();

 for(integer i=0;i<accVar.size();i++){
     findAccountName.put(accVar[i].phone,accVar[i].BillingAddress);
 }

 System.Debug(findAccountName.get('(520) 773-9050'));
```

Answer (score 5):

Billing Address is a [Compound Address Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm) and is a combination of multiple fields. For example:

```
Map<String,System.Address> amap = new Map<String,System.Address>();
Account a = [Select Name, BillingAddress from Account limit 1];
amap.put(a.Name,a.BillingAddress);
System.debug(amap);

Output:
{Edge Communications=System.Address[getCity=Austin;getCountry=null;getCountryCode=null;getPostalCode=null;getState=TX;getStateCode=null;getStreet=312 Constitution Place
```

Now, you can get all the field values individually by calling methods separately designed for each field.

```
Map<String,String> amap = new Map<String,String>();
amap.put(a.Name,a.BillingAddress.getCity());
```

Hope this helps!!!